# Google geocode api language issue

Tags: php, ios, google-maps, geocode

I want to get the results of google geocode api in English language. I am using the following link. It is returning the results in arabic language.

Am I missing something ?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=24.744165,46.676800&sensor=true&language=en

Comment: and you are trying to fetch which variable?

Comment: Show us your code and is it in PHP or IOS?

Comment: I am fetching 0 index of result array. country, administrative_area_level_1, locality

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it's already in english, but some address name are not translatable like: New York in french is always New york,  language=fr would change Saudi Arabia to Arabie saoudite

Comment: is there any possibility to get country, administrative_area_level_1 in English from 0 index

Comment: Did you check the response? Under `address_components` it's written with English characters. This question is of really poor quality. It has nothing to do with programming since it doesn't contain _any_ code what so ever (it's purely a "how does google's API work"), it's tagged with multiple unrelated tags and the answer is in the question itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$results['address_components']->formatted_address ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I already faced this issue, as far as I know, the API provide the result in the language you ask if available, otherway it use the avalible language. In your case I guess, that only arabic is available.
I'm sorry but I don't remember if it is clearly stated in the api documentation and where.

Have a look at this question: [Inconsistent language in Google Place Details API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567757/inconsistent-language-in-google-place-details-api)

and at [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport)