# How to get google map AutocompleteService result in selected language?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I search an address by google map AutocompleteService with param `language=zh` (Chinese) and this is the `address_components` it give me :

```
[
   {"long_name":"25","short_name":"25","types":["street_number"]},
   {"long_name":"Nordallee","short_name":"Nordallee","types":["route"]},
   {"long_name":"München","short_name":"München","types": ["locality","political"]},
   {"long_name":"Oberbayern","short_name":"Oberbayern","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},
   {"long_name":"Bayern","short_name":"BY","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},
   {"long_name":"德国","short_name":"DE","types":["country","political"]},
   {"long_name":"85356","short_name":"85356","types":["postal_code"]}
]
```

Only `country` type has the `long_name` in Chinese. How can I get `long_name` of types `locality, administrative_area_level_2, and administrative_area_level_1` in Chinese too?

Comment: According to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) the language code for Chinese (simplified) should be `zh-CN`. That said, I don't think you can expect every component to be translated. City names might be translated in some places/countries, but I don't think you'll ever get a street name translated into Chinese.

Comment: I try to test with `ja (Japanese)` but still only country names were translated.

Actually, what I want is city names and countries name, so I only ask for `locality, administrative_area_level_2, and administrative_area_level_1`

Comment: If I search for Shanghai, I get `上海市, 中国` and for Tokyo, I get `东京都, 日本` and that seems to work for many places around the world including Europe, America, etc. But searching for **an address** then the only translated component seems to be the country name.

Comment: Some reading: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821399 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567757/inconsistent-language-in-google-place-details-api although it might not answer your question...